# How to use several variants of input from the user?

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    string userName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a great name!", userName);
    Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like me to tell you a story?");         
}
```

And then have certain commands to be able to detect if they said any variant of the word "yes" or "no" and have all 'Yes' input go into this output:

```
Console.WriteLine("*Story*");
```

and all 'No' inputs go into this output:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like me to tell you a joke instead?");
```

i am relatively new to this, but i understand most of the VERY basic concepts.

Comment: Why not using if/else statements, or maybe using switch!

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to get a string from the user (you're asking for their name).

So do that again after you ask the user your question. Then you can use an `if-else` block to check what the user typed:

```
if (answer == "yes") {
  // "yes" stuff here
} else if (answer == "no") {
  // "no" stuff here
} else {
  // "error" stuff here (retry input?)
}
```

Of course, the user might type "YES" or " Yes ", so you can use [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) to remove any whitespace around a string, and [`ToLower()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at.aspx) to convert it to lower-case. E.g.

```
answer = answer.Trim();
answer = answer.ToLower();
```

Then you don't have to worry about case or white-space any more.

And if you wanted to handle even more cases, you could use some boolean OR conditions:

```
if (answer == "yes" || answer == "indeed" || answer == "affirmative") {
```

And I would suggest you put this code into a method, so you can call it more than once without copy+pasting it:

```
private static bool UserInputAsBoolean(string input) {
    // your code from above here,
    // with "return true;" when the answer was "yes",
    // and "return false;" otherwise.
}

// later..
if (UserInputAsBoolean(input)) {
    // yes, tell a story
} else {
    // no, no story.
}
```